# calling a function for onkeyup event in javascript for input masking

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code which will do the input masking for the date entry which is given below

```
<html>

<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } 
        else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';

        }

     "
    maxlength="10"
>
</html>
```

It takes the input in the specified format and this is working fine,, but I wanted to call this as a function and I tried this

```
<br><script type="text/javascript">

function check(t){
        var v = t;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            t = v + '/';
        return;
        } 
        else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            t = v + '/';
        return;

    }
}

</script>
<html>


<input
    type="text"
    name="date" style="text-transform: uppercase";
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="check(this.value);"
    maxlength="8"
>
</html>
```

but i didn't get the required result.  it is taking the value as ,say 11111111 where it should have taken 11/11/1111
 
What may be wrong here?

Comment: do you get a js error ?

Comment: no errors, it is taking the value as say 11111111 where it should have taken 11/11/1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give like this , If you want to reflect the changes into textbox

```
function check(t){
          var v = t;

        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {

            t = v + '/';
            document.getElementById("t1").value=t;
        return ;
        } 
        else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            t = v + '/';
            document.getElementById("t1").value=t;
        return ;

    }
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn6F4/1/)

Comment: This is awsome man !!     but I have one more question;  If this is for time input which is in a 12 hour format (HH:MM AM/PM), what all changes I have to make here? ?

Comment: take only one if condition and give `:` instead of `/`

Comment: am/pm we can give a dropdown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41622/discussion-between-bharath-rallapalli-and-messi-l)